# Restarting a task in celery

Tags: python, celery

Is there a way to restart a task in celery? Let's say if the task failed with an error or was stopped manually, I pass its uuid to some function and the task restarts

I have seen solutions where they offered to create a task with the same uuid, but the same method does not suit me